# Product-rule for Jacobian calculation, i.e. $\frac{d}{dx}(Ay)$ where A is a matrix and y a vector and both depend on x

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives, products

I'm trying to understand a paper in which the author constructs sensitivity matrices in the process of linearizing an equation. I figured that the sensitivity matrix has to be a Jacobian Matrix, however my problem is a little bit more complex (at least to me, since this kind of algebra is new to me).

I want to calculate 
$\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}}$$(\overline{G}\omega_b)$. In the paper it is actually $\frac{\partial}{\partial{p^T}}$ but I do not know if that makes sense and the author talks about a partial derivative with respect to p.
$\omega_b$ is a 3x1 column vector and $\overline{G}$ is a nx3 matrix. $p$ is a 5n-vector of 5 other vectors (each nx1) and looks like: $p=\begin{pmatrix} b\\ \lambda \\ \mu \\ \delta_u \\ \delta_v \end{pmatrix}$.
I figured the corresponding Jacobian has to be of size nx5n, however since I am actually after the derivative $\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}} \omega_b$ I figured that some kind of product-rule that creates a term $\overline{G}\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}}\omega_b$ is being used.

Here the steps that the author provides:
$\frac{\partial}{\partial{p^T}}$$(\overline{G}\omega_b)$ = $\overline{G}\frac{\partial}{\partial{p}}\omega_b - [0\ 0\ 0\ C_v\ C_u]$
The latter terms looks as if it originates from the given relationship
$\omega_g = \overline{G} \omega_b = W^T \omega_b - C_v(\omega_b)\delta_u-C_u(\omega_b)\delta_v$.

Can somebody explain if there is such a product rule and if yes, how it liiks like?
If no, then how does the author come up with the two parts?

Edit: One additional note: $C_v$ and $C_u$ are indeed of dimension nxn, so in fact each of the two parts have dimension n x 5n.

Comment: I really think that there is some kind of product rule involved here. How else would one come up with $\overline{G}\frac{\partial \omega_b}{\partial p}$ and another matrix which is subtracted... I tried breaking this down into its components, however I don't see how using this approach I can create exactly that $\overline{G}\frac{\partial \omega_b}{\partial p}$ -term. This is why I though about the product rule once again. Since such a rule has to create two n x 5n-matrices and $\overline{G}$ is n x 3, the derivative has to have 3 x 5n.

Comment: Since both $\overline{G}$ and $\omega_b$ depend on $p$ the right part looks like the derivative of $\omega_g$ with $\omega_b$ held constant. The left part, $\overline{G}\frac{\partial \omega_b}{\partial p}$, however looks like the derivative of $\omega_g$  with $\overline{G}$ held constant. So is there a product-rule similar to this (written in scalar form): $\frac{\partial}{\partial x} (u(x)v(x)) = \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (u(x)\overline{v}(x)) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} (\overline{u}(x)v(x))$ , where an overline indicates "considered constant". Is there an equivalent for vectors?

Comment: Indeed, if the following is ok, I managed to come up with the result. So please tell me if this kind of product rule is correct: $\frac{\partial}{\partial p}(\overline{G}\omega^b) = \frac{\partial}{\partial p}(\overline{G}*\omega^b) + \frac{\partial}{\partial p}(\overline{G}\omega^b*)$. A * indicates constant wrt. $p$. In the next step I wrote: $=\overline{G}\frac{\partial}{\partial p}(\omega^b) + \frac{\partial}{\partial p}(\omega^g(\omega^b*))$, using $\omega^g$ of my op. The crucial point is the second term, which is is then not a tensor of order 3 times a vector, but simly a nx5n Jacobian.